# Actions on Google check for available mobile phone

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I am currently creating a multi surface action using the actions on google SDK. In this action my users need to enter a code, if they fail to enter the code 3 times I want to check if the user has a mobile phone available so that they can enter the code via the phones keyboard.

I already tried playing around with the [surface capabilities](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/surface-capabilities#surface_capabilities_for_actions), but I noticed that there isn't a check for a specific device category. Instead the check is done based on [capabilities](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/surface-capabilities#response_branching).

What I would like to achieve is, if a user fails to enter the code by voice, if they are on a device without a keyboard ( Google Home or Google Nest Hub ) and they have a mobile phone available, they should be prompted to move the conversation to their mobile device.

I currently use the following code to determine if the user has a mobile and isn't on a mobile device already:

```
    const hasOtherDeviceWithScreen = conv.available.surfaces.capabilities.has("actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT");
    const hasOtherDeviceWithBrowser = conv.available.surfaces.capabilities.has("actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER");

    const hasAvailableMobileDevice = (hasOtherDeviceWithScreen === true && hasOtherDeviceWithBrowser === true);
    const currentDeviceHasScreen = conv.screen;
    const currentDeviceHasBrowser = conv.surface.capabilities.has("actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER");

    const handOverAvailable = (hasAvailableMobileDevice === true && currentDeviceHasBrowser === false);
```

I know that handovers can only be done with IOS & Android phones, so a check for screen + internet should detect a phone, but I am not sure how this works if more than 1 other device is available.

Does checking for a screen device and browser device guarantee that the user has a single device with these capabilities or is it possible that it returns true when the users has multiple devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `conv.surface.capabilities` is an array of all the capabilities for a particular device, while `conv.available.surfaces.capabilities` is an array of all the capabilities that the user across all of their devices.

When you are transitioning from something like a smart speaker to something like a phone, you would get a notification on every valid surface. Basically, your phone.

Checking for a web browser & screen should in general match with a mobile device, although the capability framework was designed specifically so that you wouldn't need to have direct device type checks.

Comment: Alright that is good to know, do you know if there are any plans to add new capabilities as new Google Assistant devices are being added? For instance, the only difference between a phone and a smart speaker is the browser, but if a smart speaker with browser functionality is added then I won't be able to do this handover correctly.

Comment: I can't say for sure what will change in the future, but recently the Interactive Canvas capability was added.